# Accessing images with javascript in struts

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, google-maps-api-3

Friday afternoon and my brain is on the fritz again.
I'm using javascript/jquery to place markers in an instance of google maps. Just placing them with standard values works without a hitch but I want to use custom icons. My code looks something like this.

```
var image = "/img/" + $(this).find('statusId').text()+".png";
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
    map: map,  
    position: results[0].geometry.location,  
    icon: image  
});
```

My images are the folder /img and are named 1.png, 2.png...
Without the "icon" parameter all works fine. My guess is that the script can't find the files and that Struts2 is to blame.
Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Edit: Moved the folder up one step in the hierarchy. I can now access the picture when I enter the adress in a browser wich I couldn't before. A call to marker.getIcon() returns the pathway to my file.

Comment: When you browse to "/WEB-INF/img/1.png" is it there?

Comment: What do u get if u give alert of `$(this).find('statusId').text()` ? Are you getting 1 or 2 as file name?

Comment: @justkt, good comment. No I just get an 404 error. Tried to move img-folder up one step changing the path to /img/1.png. If I enter that in the browser I get my picture. Ther rest of the script still doesn't work though form some reason.

Comment: @Karthi.L yes if do an alert like I will revceive 1 or 2 so that part work.

Comment: @Skadlig - what exactly doesn't work once `image` is set to a valid path that you know resolves to your image?

Comment: @justkt No markers are placed at all. Stupid of me to leave it out. My brain has as I said stoped working.

Comment: @Skadlig - have you tried the full URL (including server) and not just relative path?

Comment: @justkt Blimey, that worked. Well that's a bother, I can guarantee that the full URL will be a different one in production. If you post an answer refering to the comments (or just "blahblah") then I can credit you with the "win" for this one :) Edit oh and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a full valid path (http://path.to/your/image instead of /path/to/img).  This ensures that the path the API is getting is definitely to the image.  Alternatively make very sure that the relative path to that image actually works by seeing where the request goes to when you put in the relative path (via the Net tab in Firebug, for example).

If you are worried about the full path changing, consider generating the Javascript on the server side with the full URL filled in by the server or passing a variable in from the server side that has the full URL so you aren't changing hard-coded values.